# Why sometimes calling template function needs angle bracket and full type specification and sometimes not?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I have been confused by this for a while. Say if I want to call `std::make_shared` I usually have to specify the type I am making using `std::make_shared<MyClass>(...)` but I don't think angle brackets are needed in every situation. One example is the `print` function for `{fmt}` library: it is a template function, but when you call it you can do something like this: `fmt::print("Elapsed time: {0:.2f} seconds", 1.23);`, without fully specifying the types. I am just wondering why the difference and what's the rule governing when an angle bracket is needed when calling a template function?

Comment: The compiler can oftenb *deduce* the template argument from the arguments to the function. But in the case of e.g. `std::make_shared` the arguments are not really related to the template type, so this deduction can't be done.

Comment: Basically if the template types are used in the function arguments in an unambiguous way then you don't need to specify them, otherwise you do